# How to wrap a group of sibling elements within a containing div using Vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="heading">heading</h1>
  <p class="paragraph">test</p>
  <h2 class="subheading">123</h2>
  <a class="link">321</a>
</div>
```

How can I wrap the last three elements within `.container`, so that the output looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="heading">heading</h1>
  <div class="subcontainer">
    <p class="paragraph">test</p>
    <h2 class="subheading">123</h2>
    <a class="link">321</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to do it within the HTML, but in case due to some constraints that you can't modify the HTML, you can do the followings

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const subcontainer = document.createElement('div');
const lastThree = Array.from(container.children).slice(-3);

subcontainer.classList.add('subcontainer');

// move the elements into the subcontainer
lastThree.forEach(node => {
  subcontainer.appendChild(node);
});

container.appendChild(subcontainer);
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="heading">heading</h1>
  <p class="paragraph">test</p>
  <h2 class="subheading">123</h2>
  <a class="link">321</a>
</div>
```

The class name `container` is quite generic, make sure that you only select the `container` element you want, or else you might modify other elements unintentionally.

Answer (score 1):

```js
old_html = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];
firstChild = old_html.children[0];
old_html.removeChild(firstChild);
new_html = "<div class='container'>"+ firstChild.outerHTML + "<div class = 'subcontainer'>" +  old_html.innerHTML + "</div></div>";
console.log(new_html);
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="heading">heading</h1>
  <p class="paragraph">test</p>
  <h2 class="subheading">123</h2>
  <a class="link">321</a>
</div>
```